# At which point during the Torah reading on Shabbat is it appropriate to recite the prayer for the sick (מי שברך לחולים)?

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, torah-service, choleh-sick, gabbai

Is there a correct or preferred point (aliyah) during the Shabbat Torah reading at which the traditional "mi shebeirach lecholim" prayer for the sick should be recited by the gabbai?

If such a preferred point in the Torah reading exists, what is the reason for the mishebeirach lecholim prayer to be recited at this particular position?

My experience is that in many shuls the custom is for the mishebeirach lecholim to be recited immediately following the mishebeirach for the 6th aliyah. However, I am unable to find a reason or source for this practice.

Comment: If the people being prayed for are deathly ill, why wouldn’t you pray for them as early as possible?

Comment: Fair point. However, during the Shabbat morning service there is a communal prayer , customarily recited while the Torah scroll  is on the bimah, when the names of the sick are read out together.

Comment: Shabbat is not generally an appropriate time to pray for sick people (or other personal physical needs). As such, any anomalous urgent prayer for emergent situations wouldn't have a traditional set place in the service.

Comment: DoubleAA, you are theoretically correct concerning praying for personal needs. Still, the custom to pray on Shabbat for the recovery from sickness of others  is not classified as a personal request and the practice is virtually universally accepted amongst all congregations and communities; moreover, there is a special "mishebeirach" for this purpose

Comment: Praying for recovery from illness is 100% without question a personal request that is inappropriate for Shabbat and no one has ever disputed that TTBOMK. The only disputes surround when we break shabbat by praying (safek critical cases, definite critical cases, or even not then) and what sorts of indirect supplicative language wouldn't be included in the prohibition. Due to communication and medical care, there may be a lot more critical cases that people are aware of. That doesn't change the halacha. There is a special misheberach for anything anyone wants to write a misheberach for.

Comment: Double AA, I believe that the phrase "שבת היא מלזעוק" takes care of that issue

Comment: That's not a direct request for healing. You can indirectly pray for healing using only that phrase רפואה קרובה לבוא if you want. You cannot pray for healing using any normal direct phrasing (eg. an ordinary misheberach for cholim which is what you asked about). Remember making an indirect request next to a direct request doesn't make the direct request any less direct.

Comment: I was not asking about an ordinary mishebeirach (i.e., weekday) but specifically the one for Shabbat. The version of the Shabbat mishebeirach  lecholim recited in my shul (and at all other shuls I have ever attended) employs the formula "שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבוא ". Therefore, I suppose we're covered.

Comment: Making an indirect request next to a direct request doesn't make the direct request any less direct. If all you say is the line "שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבוא" then you are indeed fine by all counts. I've never seen a shul employ that strategy. Direct requests (however we define that) for healing are only possibly allowed for critically ill people (though some rishonim forbade that too).

Comment: They obviously are not the only words recited, but a formula introduced to avoid the prohibition of explicitly requesting healing and exhibiting public sorrow actually on Shabbat. The Mishna Berurah (סימן רפ"ח  ס"ק כ"ח)  is clear on permitting this method, even for a non-seriously sick person.

Comment: The Mishna Berura says כשעושין מי שבירך לחולה שאין בו סכנה אומר שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבוא which is exactly what I said too. He does not permit saying any direct requests for non-critical patients. There is no such thing as introducing a formula to avoid the prohibition of direct requests; there is just making them into indirect requests. For non-critical patients, you could say something like מי שברך אבותינו הוא יברך את פלוני אלמוני שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבוא אמן.

Comment: @Lawrence see this version which is certainly acceptable https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58111279#58111279

Answer (score 1):

This question intrigued me, as in the I Shul I Daven in, they say it after Maftir.

Yes, per the [Mishna Berura 288:28](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60388&st=&pgnum=138) one may make a Mi Sheberach for a sick person on Shabbos, so long as you say שבת היא מלזעוק ורפואה קרובה לבוא.

Although I have not been able to find a source for doing this after Shishi, I have found a interesting tidbit in [Sefer Shaarei Yemei HaPurim - Chapter 2:5 - Page 19.](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47884&st=&pgnum=31) In discussing a situation where there is a need for three Sifrei Torah, and the Shul only has two. He says that in a Shul where they say Mi Sheberach for the sick, it should be said at this point (I think he means after Shishi) and roll the Sefer Torah at the same time, in order to avoid טירחא דציבורא later, when you need to use the first Sefer Torah again.

Perhaps, due to this it became the preferred time to say a Mi Sheberach for the sick, after Shishi in many Shuls.

Comment: R' Hershel Schachter wrote that interrupting between Maftir and Haftara as your shul does is incorrect https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/957153/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-38-issues-in-krias-hatorah/ (and he has a good proof from that we don't allow you to say kaddish then; if you said a kaddish after maftir you have to repeat maftir aliyah because of the interruption).

Comment: @DoubleAA I will show to my Rabbi. Thanks.

Comment: @DoubleAA We say Kaddish after the seventh aliya. Never saw them say Kaddish after Maftir.

Comment: Bedieved the seventh aliya is a maftir. It's quite rare so you've probably never seen it (I've never seen it), but the halacha is if you find a mistake in the torah after shvi'i before kaddish then you let the seventh oleh read haftara and delay kaddish till after haftara so as to not have to take out another torah for a maftir. If you found the mistake after kaddish then you have to take out a new torah since you now need to read a maftir. See OC 282:5

Comment: This almost happened to me last shabbat. There was a smudge in a letter in the last pasuk of the parsha that stopped the reader, but it was deemed still kosher. So close!